# How to remove cantFindType warning with aspectj agent?

Tags: aspectj

With aspectj agent, I receive

```
[Xlint:cantFindType]
[Loader@203d1d93] error can't determine whether missing type org.slf4j.Logger is an instance of java.net.InetAddress
when weaving type org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
when weaving classes
when weaving
```

How I can remove this warning ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use a META-INF/aop.xml file with

```
<aspectj>

    <!--<weaver options="-verbose ">-->
    <weaver options="-warn:none -Xlint:ignore">
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ignore all warnings, the `-Xlint` argument accepts `key=value` pairs. I was digging around for solutions and I found this [thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419279).

Sadly, the reporter didn't give any example of how to use it, but it turns out it's pretty easy.

Here's an example of my configs:

```xml
    <aspectj>
         <weaver options="-Xlint:warn -Xlint:cantFindType=ignore -Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch=error">         
    </aspectj>
```